# Function declaration order matters in c language or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c, function, declaration

I get this error:

```
arthur@arthur-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ gcc -o hw -ansi hw1.c
hw1.c: In function `main':
hw1.c:27:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
hw1.c: At top level:
hw1.c:69:7: error: conflicting types for `randomStr'
hw1.c:27:18: note: previous implicit declaration of `randomStr' was here
```

While compiling this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        char *rndStr;
        rndStr = randomStr(FILE_SIZE);
        /* Do stuff */
        return 0;
}

/*Generate a random string*/
char* randomStr(int length)
{
        char *result;
        /*Do stuff*/
        return result;
}
```

If I switch the function order around it works
Why?

Comment: -1 for including way too much extraneous code. See http://SSCCE.ORG for information about why short complete examples are helpful.

Comment: you need to declare it *before* you use it.

Comment: @KevinDTimm - hw1.c:69:7: error: conflicting types for `randomStr' is very exact perhaps if you use c often.

Comment: @KevinDTimm You do realize 50% of your comments only serve up to spam up this question? I searched for about 2 hours, looking for the first error and found nothing. So what, you are basically saying I'm lazy for asking in SO or stupid for not finding it myself? Last I checked SO was doing fine w/o you insulting novice C programmers. I think you should spend your precious time answering questions if you want to help others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Except in a few exceptions, an identifier in C cannot be used before it has been declared.

Here is how to declare a function outside its definition:

```
// Declare randomStr function
char *randomStr(int length);
```

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs because symbols must generally be declared *before* they are used, not after.

A special exception to that is functions. If they are used before declaration, a particular declaration is inferred. In your case, the inferred declaration did not match the eventual definition.

Comment: Note that implicit declaration of functions has been removed since C99.

Comment: True. Also note that OP isn't using C99.

Answer (score 3):

In C89 and earlier, if the compiler saw a function *call* before a corresponding declaration or definition, it assumed that the function returned `int`.  Similarly, if you left the type specifier off of the function definition, it was assumed to return `int` (this is why a lot of older examples have an entry of just `main() {...}` instead of `int main(void) {...}`).

Since the call to `randomStr` occurs before its declaration/definition, it is assumed to return `int`, which is not compatible with `char *` (you can't assign a value of one to the other without an explicit cast), hence the error.

As of C99, implicit typing is no longer allowed.

The `-ansi` option causes `gcc` to compile as C89.  To compile as C99, use `-std=c99` instead.

I generally put the function definition before its first use within the same file, so my code reads from the bottom up (`main` is typically the last function defined in the file).  That way I don't have to worry about keeping declarations and definitions straight.

Comment: Read my post, it's unfortunate that one can't read the code from top to bottom, which is how we're used to reading text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a function declaration before any functions that use a function that isn't defined yet.

For example:

```
int doesFileExist(const char* str);
```

would go before `main()`.

The reason for this is that the C compiler runs through your code, and every time it sees a function, it looks to see if the function has been defined yet. If it can't find that function, it gives you an error. `main()` uses `doesFileExist()`, which has not been declared by the time the compiler looks at `main()`. To fix this, you can make a declaration of a function at the top, as I mentioned above. This tells the compiler that, though a function has not been filled in yet, it will be filled in later and so to treat it as if the function does exist, then go connect them later once you've found the function later on (ie, somewhere after the `main()` function).

Your second block of code works because the compiler has definitions for those functions which you use in `main()` by the time it gets there. Your first block does not work because the functions neither defined nor declared that they will be defined later.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a function prototype

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* randomStr(int length);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        char *rndStr;
        rndStr = randomStr(FILE_SIZE);
        /* Do stuff */
        return 0;
}

/*Generate a random string*/
char* randomStr(int length)
{
        char *result;
        /*Do stuff*/
        return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to nitpick, I'm actually not sure, that isn't a prototype is it?

Comment: That works, but function declarations should be in a separate .h header file