# Function defined, but still giving "function not found" error

Tags: c++

every time I ran my code which is a simple merge sort in c++, it throw an error that Merge func is not found. can any one help on this issue. the implementation is some thing like this:

```
int A[9];
void mergeSort(int low,int high) {
     if (low==high)
          return ;
     int mid=(high-low)/2;
     mergeSort(low, mid);
     mergeSort(mid+1,high);
     Merge(low,mid,high); 
}

void Merge(int l,int m ,int h) {
    int i=l;int k= l;int j=mid+1;
    int b[9];
    while (l<=m &&j<=high) {
         if (a[i]<=a[j])
              b[k]=a[i];
              k++;
         b[k]=a[j];
         j++;
         i++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: maybe define `Merge` before `mergeSort`

Comment: Have you created a function prototype for your Merge function? If not, create one, or move your Merge function above your mergeSort function.

Comment: Fyi, your mid point calculation is also incorrect. Ex: consider what happens when `low = 4` and `high = 8`. By your calculation `mid = (8-4)/2`, ie. `mid = 2`. Using your recursion, you then enter into `mergeSort(4,2)` and `mergeSort(2, 8)`. Ouch.

Comment: As @WhozCraig said, your mid calculation should be `(high + low) / 2`.  Plus, not minus.

Comment: ....or use `mid = low + (high-low)/2;` And your quick-exit is also wrong. it should exit when `(high-low) < 2`, not just when they're equal.

Comment: As stated in the answers, the reason for your erro is that you have to define or at least declare Merge before mergsort, but I'd like to point out, that your merge function doesn't make any sense what-so-ever, mostly due to some typos and missing braces.

Comment: @mokarab: C++ is "declare before you use" language. You are attempting to call a function that you have not yet declared.

Answer (score 0):

Declare function `Merge` before function `mergeSort`

```
void Merge(int l,int m ,int h);
```

Take into account that you forgot to specify braces around functions bodies.

Also substitute this statement

```
int mid=(high-low)/2;
```

for

```
int mid = ( high + low ) / 2;
```

Comment: thx every one, for your valuable comments. I think the declaration of Merge before mergeSort is need it.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to define `Merge` before `mergeSort` or supply a function definition beforehand.  Each function only knows about those that have been defined or mentioned before it.

See this other question for additional info:  [Function declaration order matters in c language or am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13297233/477563)

Answer (score 0):

Either write `Merge` function before `mergesort` or add a function declaration of `Merge` before `mergesort`.

A function declaration is required before calling that function in c++, so that compiler can understand what are the arguments required (in order) and what is the return type.

A simple function declaration for `Merge` would be:

```
void Merge(int,int,int);
```

Declare it above the `mergesort` function.

Compiler only needs to know the return value type and what are the arguments required and in what order before calling the function.

Comment: To be pedantic, in C++ it is called *function declaration*. In C++ there's no need for C term "prototype" since in C++ (as opposed to C) any function declaration in C++ is a "prototype". There are no non-prototype function declarations in C++. However, you will see the language spec to use the term *prototype* here and there at times.