# Error C2371 redefinition; different basic types

Tags: c, function

I am new to programing and I am trying to learn about functions, so I tried some questions with it to get a better understanding of it.

I am still unsure so right now I got stuck and i don't know how to continue.

I tried to make a first function in the main that has only the answers and that function calls a second function and the second one is calling to a third function

but I dont know how to fix this error i tried changing names but I am not sure what to do and even if i am doing is right
 the error I get is related to "void Ex1()" so what can I change?

```
        int main()
    {
        Ex1();
    }
    void Ex1()
    {
        int num1, num2, num3,min;
        printf("enter three diff numbers  \n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
        printf("%d", function1(min));
    }

    int function1(int sum)
    {
        int num1, num2, num3, min, max;
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            max = num1;
            min = num2;
        }
        else
        {
            max = num2; min = num1; 
        }
        if (num3 > max)
        {
            min = max;
            max = num3;
        }
        if (num3 > min&& num3 < max)
        {
            min = num3;
        }
        return min;
}
```

Comment: You do not have a min defined in Ex1, so you can't pass it to function1

Comment: oh sorry i didnt copy the code right i defined the min but i still have that problem

Comment: You might need to declare Ex1 and function1 before you call them or define them as in the answer below. Please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297233/function-declaration-order-matters-in-c-language-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are trying to *call* your functions *before* you have defined (or at least, *declared*) them. In the `C` language, when the compiler encounters a call to such an "undeclared" function, it assumes that it is of a type that returns `int` (it can normally work out what any argument types will be from the actual values given).

So when, in your `main` function, the compiler comes across `Ex1()`, it assumes that the function returns an `int` (even though this isn't actually used). Then, later, when you have your definition for `void Ex1()`, the compiler has encountered a conflicting (re-)definition - with a different return type.

To fix this, the simplest option is to put a "forward declaration" of any functions used (both `Ex1` and `function1`) ***before*** any code that calls them. In your case, this would be:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // This "system header" provides the declarations for "printf" and "scanf"
void Ex1(); // No definition here - just telling the compiler what form it takes.
int function1(int sum); // And the same here
int main()
{
    Ex1();
}
// .. . the rest of your code follows
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with passing arguments between two functions EX1 and function 1. function1 should have num1, num2 and num3 as arguments.

```
int main()
    {
        Ex1();
    }
    void Ex1()
    {
        int num1, num2, num3,min;
        printf("enter three diff numbers  \n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
        printf("%d", function1(num1, num2, num3));
    }

    int function1(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        int min, max;
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            max = num1;
            min = num2;
        }
        else
        {
            max = num2; min = num1; 
        }
        if (num3 > max)
        {
            min = max;
            max = num3;
        }
        if (num3 > min&& num3 < max)
        {
            min = num3;
        }
        return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the [order of definition](http://codepad.org/wyr75K7c), try to do it like this:

```
int num1, num2, num3, min, max;

int function1(int sum)
{

    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        max = num1;
        min = num2;
    }
    else
    {
        max = num2; min = num1; 
    }
    if (num3 > max)
    {
        min = max;
        max = num3;
    }
    if (num3 > min&& num3 < max)
    {
        min = num3;
    }
    return min;

}

void Ex1()
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    printf("enter three diff numbers  \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    printf("%d", function1(min));
}

int main()
{
    Ex1();
}
```